# How should I assign user input to an array object?

Tags: java, arrays

For the constructor I've to assign values for each of the variables from user. The variables are:

```
int rows, cols;     // How big is the treasure map
Coord [] treasureLocations; // The locations of treasures
```

For the constructor I've to get a value from the user for each of the variables. I've figured out the rows and cols but how could I handle getting a user input for treasureLocations where it can be only one input value (such as 0, 1, 2...)? **REMEMBER THAT I CANNOT ADD ANY OTHER FIELDS!** 
Thanks in advance!

```
public TreasureMap(){
      System.out.println("How many rows would you like to have? ");
      rows = kbd.nextInt();
      System.out.println("And how many columns would you like to have? ");
      cols = kbd.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Now enter the number of treasures you'd like to have: ");
      treasureLocations[] = kbd.nextInt();

}
```

Comment: If you ask someone's phone number, what will you get? A phone number, or a bag of bananas? Same here: if you ask a scanner for an integer, what will you get? An integer, or an array of coordinates?

Comment: Does your Coord class randomly assign coordinates?

Comment: The question in the println is a hint. First you have to get the number of treasures (maybe call it `numTreasures`).  Then create an array of `Coord` with size `numTreasures`.  Then loop that many times asking for coordinates and assigning to elements of the array in turn. How you ask for coordinates and create `Coord` objects to put into the array is another problem to solve.

Comment: Isn't the constructor a weird place to put code like that?

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
treasureLocations[] = new Coord [kbd.nextInt()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array while you are accepting the number of treasures.

```
public TreasureMap(){
      System.out.println("How many rows would you like to have? ");
      rows = kbd.nextInt();
      System.out.println("And how many columns would you like to have? ");
      cols = kbd.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Now enter the number of treasures you'd like to have: ");
      int[] treasureLocations = new int[kbd.nextInt()]; 
}
```

Since you have declared your array before accepting the number of elements you want, you are unable to declare the array with the exact number of elements.

Another workaround is to store that input in another variable and to loop the later input and output sequences that exact number of times.